# How to get all td value of same column by jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><textarea>col 1, row 1</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 2, row 1</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 3, row 1</textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><textarea>col 1, row 2</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 2, row 2</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 3, row 2</textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><textarea>col 1, row 3</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 2, row 3</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 3, row 3</textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><textarea>col 1, row 4</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 2, row 4</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea>col 3, row 4</textarea></td>
   </tr>
</table
```

If I click col 1, row 2, then how to get all the value col 1 from all rows and save into an array except this value?

Comment: selecting means, what to you?

Comment: But you have textarea inside td. how would you click that?

Comment: `td` elements have no value. I assume you want the value of the `textarea` *inside* the `td`?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here so we can do your work for you. Look at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com), try to do the work, and if you get stuck, come back with a specific question, showing what you've done and saying where you're stuck.

Comment: Actually click on this text area. When i just clicked into col 1, row 2 text area then I need to all the value.

Comment: Look at the [index](http://api.jqueryui.com/index) and [eq selector](http://api.jqueryui.com/eq-selector)

Comment: Yes , I want the value of  text area. T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 3):

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var colIndex=$(this).index();
    var allCellsOnTheColumn=$(this).closest('table').find('tr').find('>td:eq('+colIndex+')');
    var allCellsWithoutThisOne=allCellsOnTheColumn.not(this);
    console.log(allCellsWithoutThisOne);
});
```

This code will add a click handler on all **td** so that when you click one, it will `console.log` all the **td** on the same column, except the one clicked. Is that what you wanted?